# how to install scrapy in windows

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

When i try to install scrapy using pip command getting the following error

**pip install scrapy:**

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3xq5jpwp\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3xq5jpwp\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install 
--record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yyfldjdo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\Twisted'
```

Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Download [`scrapy`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/b7/06c19d7d7f5318ffd1d31d7cd7d944ed9dcf773981c731285350961d9b5c/Scrapy-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl) package, open cmd from that folder and run `pip install Scrapy-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

As in error it need Visual C++ 14.0.This is the link to download and install the C++ Build Tools, try installing that, then restart your PC .
Link To install Visual C++ :https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

After Installing Visual C++ open Cmd and install Scrapy
Command : `pip install Scrapy-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`